# Find text overlap in two pdfs

Tags: pdf

I have two pdfs and I want to find the text overlap between both files. With overlap I mean that the tool should indicate when at least four following words in both files agree. Is there such a tool for Ubuntu? I saw diffpdf, however the tool seems to be made to spot little differences between two pdfs. I am looking for something that is similar to a plagiarism tool. The tool should for example be able to find text overlap on page 1 in pdf 1 with a text phrase on page 10 in pdf 2.

Is there something like that for Ubuntu?

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Which version of Linux and which release number is in use? Different releases have different tools. Please click [edit] and add that to your question; please do not use Add Comment as that's our one-way channel to you.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have edited the original post